# How to extract a particular object type from json if the level is not pre-known?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a json like shown below (this is just representational):

The issue I am facing is that the Person object can be at different levels in the json. E.g. in below case it is at level 2 in case of RootNode1, at level 1 in case of RootNode2 and at level 0. Of course these levels are not limited to 2 and neither are they tied to RootNode in any way. (And these node values ar enot preknown. Only thing fixed and unique to identify Person object is `"Type": "Person"`)

I have to extract Person object in all cases.

Is there a way to achieve this through traversal in JsonPath library : https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath?

```
[
    {
        "RootNode1": [
            {
                "ABC": [
                    {
                        "DEF": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "John",
                        "Type": "Person"
                        ....
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "DAC": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "RootNode2": [
            {
                "Name": "Williams",
                "Type": "Person"
                ....
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        {
            "Name": "Sam",
            "Type": "Person"
            ....
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I would write parser manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do that is with the expression: `$..[?(@.Type == 'Person')]`, like:

```
ptx.parse(json).read("$..[?(@.Type == 'Person')]", List.class)
// ptx is ParseContext object of com.jayway.jsonpath
```

With this I can get the List of persons without caring about the level the Person object was present.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely possible.
If the readme is to be believed, he make

```
JsonPath.read(document, "$.RootNode1.ABC[1].Type");
```

For RootNode1

And

```
JsonPath.read(document, "$.RootNode2[1].Type");
```

For RootNode2

And

```
JsonPath.read(document, "$.Type");
```

it is the only way to do that I see.  but there may be simpler, I'm used to using org.json personally

Comment: Thanks. but values  "RootNode1" , "ABC" are not pre known

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this jsonpath expression

```
$..Type
```

should output

```
    [
   "Person",
   "Person",
   "Person"
]
```

at whatever level `Type` is.